# How to change the currency symbol according to language in site?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have enabled i10n, [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n), [entity translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation), [title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) and [variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable) modules and built a multilingual commerce site with language English as default language and $USD as default currency. And French and Poland as additional languages.

But I am unable to change the currency symbol in other languages.

How to translate currency symbol also?

Comment: Why do you want to change the currency symbol? Isn't $ the symbol for USD in all languages, and € the symbol for EUR in all languages?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Currency](https://www.drupal.org/project/currency) module, here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> ... provides your website with currency conversion, currency information & metadata, and amount/price display functionality.

This module facilitates [Localized price display](https://www.drupal.org/node/1931518). Here is an excerpt from that link also:

> ... displays prices/amounts based on users' locales, so they are formatted in a way that is familiar to them. The different formats can be configured at `Home » Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Currency localization`. Locales consist of a language and a country, and formatting patterns are configured per locale.

Comment: Any feedback about my answer here?